# Howto use spring security in spring integration http inbound gateway

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I want to secure my web service to only let qualified agent to call my service which is exposed by spring integration http inbound gateway, can I use spring security to do that?
the simplest way is to use a token in header for verification, however I don't want to create a wheal for such case, I want to use one standard solution in community.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Integration HTTP is fully based on Spring MVC, so, whatever you can do to secure Spring MVC with Spring Security should work the same way with Spring Integration HTTP as well. There is nothing specific in Spring Integration to restrict Spring Security configuration.